# java - File length after rename

Tags: java

a simple question, I have the following java code:

```
File file = new File("myFile.xls");
file.renameTo("mySecondFile.xls");
System.out.println(file.length());
```

If I run it, I see that the file has changed of name correctly, but strangely file.length() returns 0 (And the file is not empty)

Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Print out the length before renaming the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File` is immutable. It will always point to the filepath you created it with.

So when you rename your file, the file to which your `File` object points doesn't exist anymore (it was renamed) and you get the file length of 0.

See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
File file = new File("myFile.xls");
file.renameTo("mySecondFile.xls");
File file2 = new File("mySecondFile.xls");
System.out.println(file2.length());
```